# High Charts - Loading data with JSON not populating

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to read a JSON file and create a [pie chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) using High Charts. I am using the same example as the one at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/).

What I am trying to do is to take out the data values and put it in a separate JSON file, and then read this value using Javascript tp create the chart.

The JSON file where I have put the data looks as below :

```
 example.json

 data: [
    ["Firefox",   45.0]
    ["IE",       26.8],
    ["Safari",    8.5],
    ["Opera",     6.2],
    ["Others",   0.7]
  ]
```

However the chart is not getting populated at all. This is the JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hx1jn4wj/2/), for my changes. I think I'm messing up something in these lines.

```
 series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: []
 }]

 var chart;
 $.getJSON('example.json', function(jsonData) {
        highcharts.series[0].data = jsonData;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
 });
});
```

Could some one please help me out. Thanks !

Comment: There is a comma `,` missing after the `["Firefox",   45.0]` in the json. Make sure that is not an error. Also, you have written the chart function within the same function you call highcharts. It should be called outside. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hx1jn4wj/2/

Comment: Apart of missin comma, your json is incorrect. It should look like { "data": [["Firefox",   45.0], ["IE",       26.8], ["Safari",    8.5],["Opera",     6.2],  ["Others",   0.7]]. I recommend to you jslint to validate jsons.